# Degrees of freedom for Kuiper's Test of uniformity

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

How do you determine the degrees of freedom for Kuiper's Test of Uniformity for circular data?

I have been using various R packages for circular data (circular, CircStats) and I can't seem to find out how to get the degrees of freedom for the Kuiper's test.

Answer (score 2):

As you can check from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_test) and from the help pages of the packages that you mention, Kuiper's test does not have a degree of freedom. It proceeds like the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test), which also does not have a degree of freedom.